# vw fallback for elements that are wider than their parents

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I have a child-element with `position: absolute;` that should have the same width as the wrapper but has an ancestor that is positioned as well. Since the ancestors width is content dependent I can't 'back-calculate' a width that would always match the wrapper or even stay inside the viewport. Using a width in `vw` and the wrappers `max-width` I get the look I want but it wont work in IE8 or most Android versions.

A JS solution is easy enough but would lead to a visible jump before it's applied and a somewhat broken layout if it isn't applied at all.

So I am wondering: Is there a non-js way of enforcing a dynamic width larger than the parent-element but at most as wide as the viewport?

Comment: I'm afraid there's none but JS implementations for that. That's why vw was originally invented.

Comment: That's what I feared. I just hoped maybe someone had found a workaround for 100vw. Guess I'll have to pretty up the worst case.